# Cannot query the status of Durable Functions Workflow linked from Azure Static Web Site

Tags: azure-durable-functions, azure-static-web-app

I have successfully deployed a Blazor WASM app as an Azure Static Web App and linked it to a separately deployed Durable Functions Workflow. From the Blazor App I can successfully start a workflow. I know this because a standard response is returned with the various Uri's for querying and stopping the workflow. Also I can see the activity in the Overview of the Azure Portal.

When I try to access the `statusQueryGetUri` of the Durable Functions Workflow from a normal browser window I get a `Bad Request` response which I assume is because the request is not authenticated.

When I try to access the `statusQueryGetUri` from my Blazor App using a relative Url (i.e. from `/runtime...` I get the error `We couldn’t find that page, please check the URL and try again.`.

When I try to access the `statusQueryGetUri` from my Blazor App using a fully qualified Url (i.e. from `https://...` the Blazor App bombs with a CORS error.

Has anyone successfully got a configuration like this working?

Answer (score 0):

Currently `ActivityTriggers` are not supported by Static Web App backends. I was able to get this working by adding an `HttpTrigger` to my durable functions workflow which has a route below the `api/` path which calls the status methods such as `IDurableOrchestrationClient.GetStatusAsync()`.

Comment: Is this still the only way to get status from frontend? That is add a new azure function? What is the equivalent azure runtime api in python?

Comment: @kanna I haven't worked further on this project since - other priorities - and I can't help you with anything python related I'm afraid.